# How to display a decreasing number of images per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

How do I display different number of items per row, using CSS? Something like a pyramid style.

```
1      2        3       4        5

   6        7        8       9          
       
      10        11       12
```

Assuming those numbers are images. I am using ACF gallery.

Do you have any ideas? Maybe using flexbox?

Comment: always 12 images or you will complete the pyramid until 15?

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif , yes for now I'll be using 12 images :)

Comment: same width images or stretched?

Comment: @TemaniAfif ,let us go for stretched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox and flex like below:

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery > img {
  flex: calc(100%/3); /* 3 images per row */
  min-width: 0;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
/* until the 9th 4 images per row */
.gallery > :nth-child(-n + 9) {
  flex: calc(100%/4);
}
/* until the 5th 5 images per row */
.gallery > :nth-child(-n + 5) {
  flex: calc(100%/5);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1058/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1058/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1058/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1058/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/200">
 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/400/200">
</div>
```